# asp.net showing literal on condition

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a literal in my master page and in the code behind, sometimes I populate it with data and sometimes not. The literal is in a div so that I can access its value in javascript. The mark-up looks like this:

```
<div id="Literal1"><asp:literal .... ID="TheLiteral1" /></div>
```

How can I rewrite this so that if I don't populate the literal, I don't render the div that contains the literal.

Thanks.

Comment: yes, I meant to say mark-up. Edited

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove the `div` entirely and populate the `Literal` control with it when needed.

In the markup (see no `div`):

```
<asp:literal .... ID="TheLiteral1" />
```

In code behind:

```
TheLiteral1.Text = "<div id=\"Literal1\">...</div>";
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I want to do: how do I control the div that's around the literal?

Comment: ah ok, got it: I put the div IN the literal instead of the literal in the div. Thanks.

Comment: @frenchie - You should try giving dumb answers here... also a good way to learn ;)

Comment: Surely `TheLiteral1.Text` should be set to `"<div id="Literal1">...</div>"`? It seems that frenchie understood what you meant, but you might still want to fix your answer.

Comment: @hdv: yes, I saw it and got it.

Comment: @hvd - Gaaa... serves me right for copy pasting and assuming all is right. Thanks.

Comment: And what I overlooked in my comment too is that `"` inside doublequoted strings don't work :)

Answer (score 0):

You may create your own custom control - and render it in a different way according condition